# Creating Sub Folder in S3 bucket with special Characters?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement like creating a sub folder like "test+++" but when i use this name a subfolder is created in name "test%2B%2B%2B". I tried url encoding and escape special charater but was unsuccessful. I am using Amazon multipart to upload video.

```
s3key =URLEncoder.encode("/test123+++/0b14e09f0fe17fe715dec857e3fd2efa.mp4", "UTF-8");

InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest(s3bucketName, s3key);       
initRequest.withObjectMetadata(md);
configureInitiateRequest(initRequest);
InitiateMultipartUploadResult initResponse = s3Client.initiateMultipartUpload(initRequest);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to create a sub-folder with special character "test+++" in S3 bucket using java.

Comment: It works fine via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/), so the problem is probably with the code that you use to create the object. Your code snippet does not show how you set the value of `s3key`.

Comment: I have tried String s3Key =   /test123+++/0b14e09f0fe17fe715dec857e3fd2efa.mp4

String s3Key = URLEncoder.encode("/test123+++/0b14e09f0fe17fe715dec857e3fd2efa.mp4", "UTF-8");

Comment: Please edit your question rather than putting code in a comment.

Comment: I have edited the question and also tried without using URLEncoder.encode

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of AWS S3:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Take in consideration the following restriction:

> Bucket names must comply with DNS naming conventions.

With that said, you can also take a look to the documentation for the DNS naming syntax: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Usually those names should be mapped as a text string including characters from the `alphabet (a-z)`, `digits/numbers (0-9)`, `minus sign (-)`, and `period (.)` which are used for delimitation.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am creating sub folders inside S3bucket. I tried to create folders directly with name for eg "test+++" the folder just got created but when I tried from code it created "test%2B%2B%2B". I tried using URLEncoding but faced same issue. I am using JAVA 8.